# Pipe erro: Type PaginatePipe is part of the declarations of 2 modules

Tags: javascript, angular

Estou com o seguinte erro no meu template:

> Type PaginatePipe is part of the declarations of 2 modules:

Eu estou fazendo o *import* do pipe `PaginatePipe` em 2 módulos, o que eu achava que iria funcionar normalmente, porém não funcionou.

Exmemplo:

Assim estou fazendo nos componentes

**Importação do ng2-pagination**

> import {PaginatePipe, PaginationService, PaginationControlsCmp, IPaginationInstance} from 'ng2-pagination';

**@Component({})**

> directives: [PaginationControlsCmp],
>     providers: [PaginationService],
>     pipes: [PaginatePipe]

**Template** (Não rolou botar aqi os '<' da tag do pagination-controls)

> pagination-controls (pageChange)="getPage($event)" id="server">/pagination-controls>

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]. Algumas dicas: O site é voltado pro público lusófono, então seus posts precisam ser em português apenas, não há necessidade de escrever em inglês também. Tente usar títulos descritivos nas suas perguntas, a maioria dos acessos das perguntas vêm por causa do título. Evite usar títulos com "Help", "Ajuda", provavelmente se você está postando aqui é porque precisa de ajuda, é redundância escrever no título. Foque sua pergunta em explicar o problema, na mensagem de erro, e no código. Tente sempre publicar um [mcve]. Use as tags corretamente, é Angular**JS** ou Angular**2**?

Comment: opa, obrigado pelas dicas, vão ser seguidas muito bem a apartir de agora :D e relacionado ao erro, é em angular2, eu estou com esse erro a um tempo ja, e ate agr nao consegui nada

Comment: Adiciona o código que importa esses módulos pra vermos. Tenta dar uma explicada em como sua aplicação usa os módulos, mas tente ser breve e explicativo.